# VBA - Function doesn't work using inputs from other worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, function, worksheet

I want to create a function in VBA that returns the variation between two prices within a user-specified interval. For that I created the following function:

```
Public Function ret(p, i)

    ret = (p / Cells((p.Row - i), p.Column)) - 1

End Function
```

Where the input 'p' represents the last observation of a vector of prices, and the input 'i' refers to the number of periods I want to move up in the price vector.

The function works fine when I use inputs that are in the same worksheet where the function is defined. However, when employ inputs from other worksheets the function returns '#VALUE!'.

What is the function missing to work "globally"?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use

```
ret = (p / p.parent.Cells((p.Row - i), p.Column)) - 1
```

cells alone refers to the current sheet

Comment: Solution from Tim Williams is  straightforward and it includes a error handling.

Answer (score 3):

Avoiding `Cells`:

```
Public Function ret(p, i)
    If p.Row > i Then
        ret = (p / p.Offset(- i, 0)) - 1
    Else
        ret = "???"
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper place to put your **UDF** code is not inside a `Worksheet_Module`, these are usually for Worksheet related events, such as `Worksheet_Change` , etc.

If you want to use a **UDF** from all worksheets, put it in a regular Module, so it's available to all worksheets.

Also, you should define your **UDF** parameters properly, and not leave them empty.

In your case use the code below inside a regular Module:

```
Public Function ret(p As Range, i As Long)

    ret = (p.Value / Cells(p.Row - 1, p.Column)) - 1

End Function
```

*Screen-shot of VBAProject Explorer*

[image]

Comment: Using an unqualified `Cells` in a UDF is asking for trouble.  It's likely that the reurn value will change as the ActiveSheet changes.

Comment: @TimWilliams it did'nt in my tests, but I was too tired when I wrote it, I forgot all about `Range.Offset`, you solution is better